# in next.js, at page loading show error in console: 404 not found. although page load successfully

Tags: next.js, html5-video, http-status-code-404, error-console

Using react with next.js and tailwind, when my website start loading i see in the console the error:

"GET http://localhost:3000/true 404 (Not Found)".

same error in console show again after the website loading finished.

[image]

the website eventually load successfully and its working good but still i see that error in the console every time i refresh the page.

i suspect the error coming from this block of code in my index.tsx file:

```
<div className='h-[90vh] w-full'>
        <video autoPlay loop muted poster='true' className="w-screen h-full absolute object-cover z-[-1]">
                <source src="/videoBG.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>

        <About />
</div>
```

cause when i remove that video element and refresh the page i dont see in the console the error anymore..

in that code i use a local video file(located in my public folder) as background. the video work fine as my background with no problem. but yet that error in the console still there . what can be the reason for it??

thank you

i tried to change the path of the video file in the source element, but didn't seems to make any difference

```
<source src="/videoBG.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

i looked for answer in google and didn't found anything addressing that issue